# Tableau- Filtering based on another element

Tags: database, parameters, filtering, tableau-api

I have multiple tables with one common element (ID). The first table has is the only one that has the ID and First Name. In a dashboard, I am trying to create a filter where when I type in or select the First Name, all data from all tables relating to the First Name's ID would populate.

FYI, I don't want to join the data. My actual tables are big data from multiple sources I would like to find an alternative route to this.

I also tried to create a parameter for the First Name and then created a Calculated Field with

```
IF [Parameter]=[Name] 
THEN [ID] 
ELSE NULL 
END
```

but this didn't work. I am very new to Tableau and I'm thinking that there must be a way where the choosing a Name would trigger the ID and its relevant data.

Comment: Please post some code to show your effort on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

create multiple sheets with different tables where each sheet will be collected to individual table.

Now create a filter and apply the filter to all worksheets and then go to dashboard and apply filter, Dash board should change.